# Codeigniter - use query result in another query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, object

In my controller I have a list of results from a query (up to 10 rows or so). I am trying to use the results of the query to use in another. For example, the first query pulls out 'agency_ID' (the data I wish to use in the next query)

CONTROLLER:

```
$data['list_report'] = $this->reports_model->filteredReport();
$data['area_data'] = $this->reports_model->getAreaDataReport($data['list_report']);
```

MODEL:

```
function getAreaDataReport($data)
{       
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT COUNT(asa.sector_ID) AS area_count, asa.*, ags.sector
    FROM agencies_sector_association asa, agencies_sector ags WHERE agency_ID IN ('. $data->agency_ID .')
    AND asa.agency_ID = ags.ID
    GROUP BY agency_ID');
    return $query->result();
}
```

I get this error:

```
Message: trying to get property of non-object codeigniter model
```

When I print_r the first query results I get the following.

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [case_ID] => 1 [reference_ID] => IFSOU001 [ID] => 1 [agency_ID] => 1 [agency_name] => Agency1 [task_ID] => 3 [task] => Domestic violence [outcome_ID] => 3 [outcome] => Protection plan no longer in place [creation_date] => 2012-12-05 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [case_ID] => 3 [reference_ID] => NEW REFERENCE ID [ID] => 2 [agency_ID] => 1 [agency_name] => Agency1 [task_ID] => 1 [task] => Transport [outcome_ID] => 8 [outcome] => Bespoke needs based assessment received [creation_date] => 2013-05-01 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [case_ID] => 6 [reference_ID] => REFERENCE ID [ID] => 6 [agency_ID] => 1 [agency_name] => Agency1 [task_ID] => 2 [task] => Counselling [outcome_ID] => 2 [outcome] => Improved school attendance [creation_date] => 2013-05-01 ) )
```

My question is how do I use the agency_ID of the first statement in my next statement as an array so it wont just return one row. From this result I get 3 'agency_ID' results back, but it could be more in future searches.

Many thanks to all those who can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$data` is an array of objects containing just the one object.

Replace `$data->agency_ID` with `$data[0]->agency_ID`

This will give you the `agency_ID` member variable of the object stored at position `[0]` in the `$data` array.

Assuming you have more than one object in the array of results you will need to get the ids and store them in a string then use this string in your query

```
$id_str = '';
foreach($data as $agency) {
    $id_str .= $agency->agency_ID . ', ';
}
$id_str = rtrim($id_str, ', '); //remove the trailing comma and space
```

Now replace `$data->agency_ID` in your query with `$id_str`

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to reformat your result array so that it fits into the `IN` statement. In a format like `23, 17, 20`.
The `$this->reports_model->filteredReport();` should return with `result_array()`.

```
$data['list_report'] = $this->reports_model->filteredReport();

$data_list = array();

foreach($data['list_report'] as $lp) {
    $data_list[] = $lp->agency_ID;
}

$data['area_data'] = $this->reports_model->getAreaDataReport(implode(',',$data_list));
```

And then just use the string in your query:

```
function getAreaDataReport($data)
{       
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT COUNT(asa.sector_ID) AS area_count, asa.*, ags.sector
    FROM agencies_sector_association asa, agencies_sector ags WHERE agency_ID IN ('.$data.')
    AND asa.agency_ID = ags.ID
    GROUP BY agency_ID');
    return $query->result();
}
```